# CSS Making margins independent of text inside parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

For my editor I need a vertical line to run from the bottom of draggableNode (the blue box) to the bottom of the page. When the text inside of the div draggableNode exceeds one line, the vertical line is shifted down as well, see below:

[image]

I can see that the vertical line is dependent on the end of the text whereas I would like it to be dependent on the bottom of draggableNode, regardless of how many lines the text is. How could I go about doing that?

CSS

```
.draggableNode {
  width: 100px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left:15px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #29e;
  color: white;
  z-index:9995;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: .5em;
}

.verticalLine {
    border-left: 3px solid #000000;
    position: relative;
    margin-left:50px;
    z-index:-1;
    height: 613px;
    width:0;
    margin-top: 8 px;
}
```